# "/bin/sh: python: command not found" error while trying to run python on VSCode (mac, anaconda)

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I've just downloaded Anaconda and Python extension for Visual Studio Code. I created a new file, selected the language mode as Python, and the interpreter is set to the Conda one. I can't run anything in my python file because of that error. I know something is not installed correctly, but I do not know how to go about with it.

Comment: open anaconda, open Spyder and then create new python file and try running that

Comment: It's called `python3`, not `python`. Configure the extension appropriately.

Comment: You can also fix this by starting VS Code from a terminal where your PATH is set correctly, instead of starting it from the MacOS GUI.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python` to replace, and this does not rely on `zsh`.

Comment: The OP hasn't told us they have Homebrew installed, so it may or may not exist. They _definitely_, by contrast, have `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: This fixed it.  But now I get this error on Mac: **xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools.**